# Running sum on pairRDD/ a Map data structure until a threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap, rdd

I have a dataset from which I created a `pairRDD[K,V]`
*v = number of datapoints under each key)]*

```
val loadInfoRDD = inputRDD.map(a => (a._1.substring(0,variabelLength),a._2)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

> (dr5n,108)
>   (dr5r4,67)
>   (dr5r5,1163)
>   (dr5r6,121)
>   (dr5r7,1103)
>   (dr5rb,93)
>   (dr5re8,11)
>   (dr5re9,190)
>   (dr5reb,26)
>   (dr5rec,38088)
>   (dr5red,36713)
>   (dr5ree,47316)
>   (dr5ref,131353)
>   (dr5reg,121227)
>   (dr5reh,264)
>   (dr5rej,163)
>   (dr5rek,163)
>   (dr5rem,229)

I need to allocate each Key to an RDD partition, after this stage, I `zipWithIndex` the keys of this RDD

```
val partitioner = loadTree.coalesce(1).sortByKey().keys.zipWithIndex
```

> (dr5n,0)
>   (dr5r4,1)
>   (dr5r5,2)
>   (dr5r6,3)
>   (dr5r7,4)
>   (dr5rb,5)
>   (dr5re8,6)
>   (dr5re9,7)
>   (dr5reb,8)
>   (dr5rec,9)
>   (dr5red,10)
>   (dr5ree,11)
>   (dr5ref,12)
>   (dr5reg,13)
>   (dr5reh,14)
>   (dr5rej,15)
>   (dr5rek,16)
>   (dr5rem,17)

But in order to get better load distribution in each partition, I need to run through values, starting from key1(in the sorted order), and calculate a **running sum** on values until a **Threshold** value and set all the keys to a same value (partition number in this case, starting from 0)

Say, threshold = 10000, then

> (dr5n,0)
>   (dr5r4,0)
>   (dr5r5,0)
>   (dr5r6,0)
>   (dr5r7,0)
>   (dr5rb,0)
>   (dr5re8,0)
>   (dr5re9,0)
>   (dr5reb,0)
>
> (dr5rec,1)
>
> (dr5red,2)
>
> (dr5ree,3)
>
> (dr5ref,4)
>
> (dr5reg,5)
>
> (dr5reh,6)
>   (dr5rej,6)
>   (dr5rek,6)
>   (dr5rem,6)

I tried creating a new map, creating a set of keys which could be grouped and inserted them into the new map.

Is there any expert way to achieve the same ? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just do `RDD.repartition(newPartitionCount)`?